# Firefox DevTools - "CSS Grid is not in use on this page"

Tags: css, firefox, css-grid, firefox-developer-tools

I'm building my first application using CSS Grids.

Using Firefox's *DevTools*, I'm able to to highlight the Grid's tracks by clicking "`# grid`" next to an element in the "`Rules`" pane :

[image]

But when I click the "`Layout`" pane, it *always* shows "`CSS Grid is not in use on this page`":

[image]

Why is that?

(I'm using the latest Firefox version available today, "`62.0.2`")

**UPDATE**: Here's [an example project](https://github.com/electrotype/dev-tool-css-grid).

**UPDATE 2**: It *does* work when I create a new, fresh, profile! But it doesn't work with my current profile, even when I start in *safe mode*, with all add-ons disabled... I guess I'll customize a new profile!

Comment: Just checked [a Grid layout](https://jsfiddle.net/q5e20knd/15/) in Firefox 62.0.2. Both "Rules" and "Layout" panes working properly. Not getting your error.

Comment: Is the grid not doing what you expect, or are you just concerned with the message?

Comment: I also cannot duplicate. It shows as expected for me. It took about 2 seconds to load. It showed the "CSS Grid is not in use" message during those 2 seconds.

Comment: @DamienBlack the grid works just fine! But I'd like to try the `Layout` pane...

Comment: @Michael_B I have the same problem with the example you linked! Even in safe mode, with all add-ons disabled. I guess I should try with a fresh Firefox installation/profile.

Comment: Update #2: It *does* work with a new profile.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you indeed this is a bug in Firefox, I'm using the latest version of developer edition **85.0b9**, I faced the same issue. You can clearly see, I've display as Grid still it says CSS Grid not in use on this page.

[image]

Issue - It happens when you open it in the default or the 1st Tab, it's not setting some tab-value there. The bug is still not fixed by Bugzilla's dev team, open from past 2 years. Let's hope they fix in future.

Issue Link - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1492370

**Solution - Just duplicate your tab, it'll work like a charm.**